# CANNOT receive iCloud calendar on Evolution

Tags: evolution, calendar, caldav

I was trying to set up iCloud Calendar on Evolution (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).

After everything settled, I found that I could not **RECEIVE** the calendar online, which says:

> The calendar backend servicing “Personal” encountered an error.
>   The reported error was “Failed to read resource: HTTP error code 404 (Not Found)”.

[Error Report Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taS9y.png)

However, when I add a new appointment in the Evolution, the appointment will also appeared on iCloud Calendar or masOS Calendar.

Therefore, I suppose my settings are correct because the pushing service works pretty well.

Is there anyone encountered this problem before? I am a newbie in Ubuntu, the Calendar function works perfect on Evolution in Manjaro, and the settings are all the same.

I have already read the posts on Ask Ubuntu, but no one has post questions like this.

The settings are as followings:
[Find Calendars Shows Calendar List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNfUm.png)
[Choose Calendar from Find Calendars and get URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znDop.png)